# Change variables value inside nested function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I have function that loops and inside that function I call another function (which should change "newArray[x]" value, but it doesn't do anything).

```
function UTF8() {
        newArray = ["0011", "0001"]
        newArray.forEach(x => {
            binaryToHexadecimal(newArray[x]);
            console.log(newArray[x])
        });
        console.log(newArray[0])
}

function binaryToHexadecimal(string) {
    if (string === "0000") {
        return string = "0";
    }
    else if (string ==="0001") {
        return string = "1";
    }
    else if (string ==="0010") {
        return string = "2";
    }
    else if (string ==="0011") {
        return string = "3";
    }
    else if (string ==="0100") {
        return string = "4";
    }

}
UTF8();
```

Comment: arguments are called by value. Assigning a new value to the parameter *never* changes the variable or property that you pass as argument.

Comment: **1.** `newArray[x]` is `undefined` because `x` will be either `0011` or `0001` and both `newArray["0011"]` and `newArray["0001"]` don't exist. **2.** that's not how you replace a value from an array

Comment: 1) you're using forEach, so `x` isn't the index, it's the array element itself 2) you would have to use `newArray[x] = binaryToHexadecimal(newArray[x]);` 3) this is precisely what [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for

Comment: `["0011", "0001"].map(b => parseInt(b, 2).toString(16).toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is setting a *local* variable, it has no control over whatever variable was used to pass that value.

Just return the value you want from the function.  For example:

```
return "0";
```

Then when *calling* the function, use that value to set your array element as needed:

```
newArray[x] = binaryToHexadecimal(newArray[x]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`.

And here  `return string = "0";` you can directly return the value.

```js
function UTF8() {
        newArray = ["0011", "0001"]
        return newArray.map(x => {
            return binaryToHexadecimal(x);
        });
}

function binaryToHexadecimal(string) {
    if (string === "0000") {
        return "0";
    }
    else if (string ==="0001") {
        return "1";
    }
    else if (string ==="0010") {
        return "2";
    }
    else if (string === "0011") {
        return "3";
    }
    else if (string ==="0100") {
        return string = "4";
    }

}
const result = UTF8();
  console.log(result);
```